# how to set null value to email column in sales order address table

Tags: email, sales-order, magento2.2.6

I want to set the email field in sales order address table to null.But if i give  $address->setEmail('')->save();
Its saying that the email is not in correct format.I am able to save the customer email to null in sales order table.$sales->setCustomerEmail('');
Its working for sales order but not working in sales order address table.Can any one help to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: just save it without using setEmail(). It has default value as null.

Comment: I want this for delete customer requirement.If the customer click the delete button it will check the sales order and address tables and update his email to null.

Comment: can you please update your question with what you have done so far.

Comment: It will check the customer wheather he has any pending orders.If he has no pending orders it will update all the fields to null in sales order address table and update the email to null in sales order table. $sales->setCustomerEmail('');.Its updating the current customer to null in sales order. But if i give the same thing in sales order addres table $address->setEmail('')->save();.Its giving error not in correct format